# How to get Email of the user who performed an activity in Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-drive-activity-api

I am trying to get data from Drive Activity API. The data needs to have the following 4 arguments:

> 1. User Information
> 2. Filename
> 3. Activity Type (Edit, Delete, Copy)
> 4. Timestamp

I used the following code to get the required data:

```
function listDriveActivity() {
  
  var arr = [];

  const request = {
    pageSize: 10
  };
  try {

    const response = DriveActivity.Activity.query(request);

    const activities = response.activities;

    if (!activities || activities.length === 0) {
      Logger.log('No activity.');
      return;
    }
    
    for (const activity of activities) {
      // get time information of activity.
      var time = getTimeInfo(activity);
      // get the action details/information
      var action = getActionInfo(activity.primaryActionDetail);
      // get the actor's details of activity
      var actors = activity.actors.map(getActorInfo);
      // get target information of activity.
      var targets = activity.targets.map(getTargetInfo);   
      arr.push(actors,targets,[action],[time]);
 
    }
    Logger.log(arr);

  } catch (err) {

    Logger.log('Failed with an error %s', err.message);
  }
}


function getOneOf(object) {
  for (const key in object) {
    return key;
  }
  return 'unknown';
}

function getTimeInfo(activity) {
  if ('timestamp' in activity) {
    return activity.timestamp;
  }
  if ('timeRange' in activity) {
    return activity.timeRange.endTime;
  }
  return 'unknown';
}


function getActionInfo(actionDetail) {
  return getOneOf(actionDetail);
}


function getUserInfo(user) {
  if ('knownUser' in user) {
    const knownUser = user.knownUser;
    const isMe = knownUser.isCurrentUser || false;
    return isMe ? 'people/me' : knownUser.personName;
  }
  return getOneOf(user);
}

function getActorInfo(actor) {
  if ('user' in actor) {
    return getUserInfo(actor.user);
  }
  return getOneOf(actor);
}

function getTargetInfo(target) {
  if ('driveItem' in target) {
    const title = target.driveItem.title || 'unknown';
    return 'driveItem:"' + title + '"';
  }
  if ('drive' in target) {
    const title = target.drive.title || 'unknown';
    return 'drive:"' + title + '"';
  }
  if ('fileComment' in target) {
    const parent = target.fileComment.parent || {};
    const title = parent.title || 'unknown';
    return 'fileComment:"' + title + '"';
  }
  return getOneOf(target) + ':unknown';
}
```

This is the example output, when there is some activity in the drive by a user:

```
User Information: people/107464693787053536449
Filename: Timesheet 
Activity Type: Edit 
Timestamp: 2022-04-05T04:51:41.862Z
```

Now, I want to get the user email in User information rather than user id. Can you please guide me how should I do it? Is there any method/function that I could follow?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use People API if you want to get more information about the user, including the email address:

> **personName**: The identifier for this user that can be used with the People API to get more information. The format is `people/ACCOUNT_ID`. See https://developers.google.com/people/.

More specifically, call [people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) with `personFields` set to `emailAddresses`:

```
function getEmailAddress(resourceName = "people/ACCOUNT_ID") {
  const optionalArgs = {
    personFields: "emailAddresses",
    fields: "emailAddresses(value)"
  }
  const contact = People.People.get(resourceName, optionalArgs);
  const emailAddress = contact.emailAddresses[0].value;
  return emailAddress;
}
```

Comment: Can you please guide how can I get "people/ACCOUNT_ID"? Thank you

Comment: @Roomi It's what you get from Drive Activity API. In the example you provided, it corresponds to `people/107464693787053536449`.

Comment: Oh sorry..ok, I am testing it. Thank you..

Comment: I have used this id "people/110486077259925290027", but it is showing empty output like this:
{}

Comment: Hi @Roomi, if you try with `people/me`, do you get your address? I'm thinking maybe the user whose data you want to access is not in your contacts and you cannot access their info.

Comment: No, I just want to get the email address of the person who performed the activity on google drive. I can access their id but not email.

Comment: @Roomi In this case, I don't think you can get the email address of that account. To get more information about the `personName` you get from Drive Activity, you should use People API. Is there any information you can get from People API at all, for this user?

Comment: In your answer, you shared a code snippet that gets the user id and returns the email as an output. But it returned empty when I tried to run it.

Comment: @Roomi That's why I asked if you can get your email if you provide `people/me` as a parameter (`me` is a special keyword that refers to the requesting user, that is, you). I can certainly return the email address of an account if I use the script I provided, so most likely the problem is that you're unauthorized to get information for that account. It's hard to debug this since I cannot reproduce the behavior you're getting, but in order to troubleshoot this, if you remove `fields: "emailAddresses(value)"` and log `contact` (`Logger.log(contact)`), what data (if any) is logged?

Comment: @lamblichus when I logged the contact, this is the output I got:
`etag=%EgUBCS43PhoEAQIFByIMaUtiblZUNVBPNkU9,resourceName=people/110486077259925290027`.  I performed an activity in Drive so this is my credentials.

Comment: @Roomi `I performed an activity in Drive so this is my credentials` This is strange, if you try with `people/me` do you get the same? If you call https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list with `resourceName: people/me` and `personFields: emailAddresses`, do you get the email addresses for at least some connections?

Comment: If I perform an activity from my personal account and another account then the user id is different in both cases, and it should be that way. But I do not get email in any case.

Comment: @Roomi Of course the user id will be different in this case, I'm not asking that. If you use the special keyword `me` to get the current user (`people/me`) when calling `people.get`, you don't get the email address either?